# transform web.config using msbuild command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, web-config-transform

Looking to setup jenkins to deploy my web app I'm using the script

```
msbuild WEB.csproj /p:Configuration=stage /t:Build /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:OutputPath=c:\test /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```

I get the web application in `_PublishedWebsite` however the `web.config` needs to get transformed. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

from this post [TFS 2012 not copying transformed Web.Config to _PublishedWebsite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884342/tfs-2012-not-copying-transformed-web-config-to-publishedwebsite?rq=1)

add `/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false` to the command solved the issue